# How can i see my installed Django on Centos 7 server?

Tags: django, centos7

I newly installed django on centos 7 server but how can i see my working django website.
I have server ip address and also website. Firstly Do I need to change the domain dns with the server ip address?

In addition i didnt installed to the root, i installed django to the root/iki path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't deploy your app and just installed Django. For deploying your Django app on a server you should use nginx.

You can find a good guide for Django deployment [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).